# Icons to insert new page disappeared

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Someone could tell me how can I get back the icons of my wordpress?

Currently I'm like:

[image]

I want to return to normal, thus:

[image]

Does anyone know which css can move?

Comment: Did you edit any core wordpress files?  Have you tried disabling plugins one by one?

Comment: It really was. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I restored the css files of wordpress, so he returned to work.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Chris Herbert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1667136/chris-herbert), try **disabling plugins** one by one.
It will solve the problem.

If you've edited any core wordpress file, consider **reinstalling wordpress** from wp-admin.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I managed to solve the problem by restoring the original css files wordpress